# Moff Gideon's dark saber, what is this, and is he a Force user?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the last episode of The Mandalorian, we see Moff Gideon's TIE fighter crash on Navarro.

He cuts himself out of the wreckage with a strange weapon others have called a "Darksaber."

What is this weapon? How did he acquire it?

And does this give any indication that Moff Gideon is a Force user?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### What is this weapon?

It's not *a* darksaber, it's **the** Darksaber.

> The Darksaber was **an ancient and unique black-bladed lightsaber** created by Tarre Vizsla, the first Mandalorian ever inducted into the Jedi Order, prior to 1019 BBY.
>  <sub>*source:* [Wookieepedia - Darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber)</sub>

[image: Sabine Wren wielding the Darksaber] 
 <sub>Sabine Wren wielding the Darksaber.</sub>

### How did he acquire it?

No one knows yet. The last known possessor of the Darksaber was [Bo-Katan Kryze](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze) who was gifted it by [Sabine Wren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sabine_Wren) before [The Mandalorian](https://www.starwars.com/series/the-mandalorian) showed [Moff Gideon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gideon) as the current user in  [S01E08 - Chapter 8: Redemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_8:_Redemption) (season one finale).

The episode's subtext suggests that Gideon stole it from Mandalore during the [Great Purge of Mandalore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Purge), in which the evil Galactic Empire wiped out most of the Mandalorian people.

### And does this give any indication that Moff Gideon is a force user?

No. Despite the Darksaber's origin story and being possessed by at least two other force users¹, it has been possessed and wielded by several other non-force users² with no ill effect.

---

¹ <sub>[Darth Maul](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maul) and [Kanan Jarrus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kanan_Jarrus) were force users that possessed and wielded the [Darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber)</sub>

² <sub>[Pre Vizsla](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pre_Vizsla), [Sabine Wren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sabine_Wren) and [Bo-Katan Kryze](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bo-Katan_Kryze) were non-force users that possessed and wielded the [Darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber)</sub>